# Android UI - dynamic button alignment change

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

I have following xml

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <NestedScrollView>
        <ConstraintLayout>
            <RecycleView/>
        </ConstraintLayout>
    </NestedScrollView>
    <Button BottomTo_BottomOf = parent/>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

When I load the screen that I want the button to be stick at the screen bottom.
I am loading some elements dynamically (based on user action) in the recycleview and once the recycleview has elements more then the screen size then I want the button alignment to be changed from screen bottom to the end of the content and visible once user scroll through all the contents

Comment: How much of your layout is there to try to accommodate the positioning of the button and how much to support the other aspects of your design? For example, you have a _RecyclerView_ nested within a _ConstraintLayout_ that is nested within a _NestedScrollView_ which seems redundant and everything is held by an outer _ConstraintLayout_. If the button could move inside the _NestedScrollView_ would you still need the outer _ConstraintLayout_? Maybe everything you posted is needed. If not, it may help to show the minimum skeletal layout your design needs _without_ the button.

Answer (score 1):

Add these attribute to `Button`:

```
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Add these attribute to `NestedScrollView`

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomButtonId" <--Id of bottom button-->
```

For reference try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button6">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                tools:listitem="@layout/imagepost_buttons"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bottom Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below tag to the button -

```
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Comment: Initially  m using it but when I have more content in recycleview then I have to push the button at the end rather then keeping it at the screen bottom and  property which u r suggesting I have already mentioned it in my question

Comment: If you want to add it at the bottom of the content then you need to add it below recyclerview.